# PowerBI weighted average

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I struggle with calculating rolling weighted average in PowerBI but with **pre-defined weights**

[image]

In other words, I need to calculate a weighted average for each "window" of data where each data has a weight assigned depending how old the data is in the particular time frame.

Is there anyone who can help, I would be grateful! :)

Comment: why don't you just merge the table to weights into the original table? then you should be able to get a weighed amount, and use that in any calculations

Comment: Thank you for comment. I though about it, but this "merge" should be dynamic depends what window is taken, correct ? If yes, what type of DAX function do you recommend ?

Comment: you are correct, I read the question wrong

Comment: but what type of query command should I use ? Keeping looking on the internet but can not find. Would be grateful for tips

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much of a DAX'er. Im sure someone else will be able to help

Comment: Case is closed.